# Is ISAPI_Rewrite install

Tags: iis, iis-6, isapi-rewrite

I buy Windows share Host (IIS6) and my panel is Plesk.
I create a site in PHP(Drupal) in Apache and I want move it to Windows host.
.htaccess file not worked :(

I don't know is ISAPI_Rewrite install,How to understand this?
Can I install it in my panel?or How to install ISAPI?

My English language not well,Please edit my question and answer soon as possible :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely permissions. 
Make sure you go to Helicon installation folder --> Properties --> Security. In security tab, please, delete the PLESK users from the list completely. And allow the User, that runs application pool of a web-site, to have 'Read' and 'List Folder Content' permissions.

Do the same for .htaccess in the root of your web-site.

Comment: are you sure?!
I have  this list of user.how to set permission for them?
1-Administrators 
2-SYSTEM 
3-Plesk FTP User 
4-Plesk Domain User 
5-Plesk IIS User

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a shared hosting, ISAPI_Rewrite has to be installed globally on the server and you simply use the .htaccess file under your site. So you should consult your hosting whether they have the product installed.

Also please notice that Plesk is likely to restrict permissions that may prevent ISAPI_Rewrite from operating properly. List folder content permission should be given to the folder containing .htaccess, ,htaccess itself should be granted Reed/Write permissions.